# How can I retrieve the source code of a DLL that is protected with Eazfuscator.NET?

Tags: dll, deobfuscation, eazfuscator

I use a reflector to retrieve the source code of C# DLLs.
However, I have a DLL that is protected with Eazfuscator.NET. The reflector cannot retrieve the code from this DLL.

How can I retrieve the code from this DLL?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: That's why people use obfuscator tools - to prevent you from doing this

Comment: Ask the developer how much the source costs. ;)

Comment: Questions like this are allowed? Perhaps we can explain how to steal cars as well?

Comment: i can't belive you got two upvotes...